# Small $\ell^p$ spaces are obtainable from $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

I've seen that in a lot of books there is written that $$l^p=L^p(X,\Sigma,\mu),$$
where $X=\Bbb N, \Sigma=P(\Bbb N), \mu=\#$, ($\#$ is the counting measure). I would like to see how to prove it, because I've tried but there are a lot of things that don't convince me. Do you know where I can find this proved, or some suggestion to prove it?

Comment: If you have tried proving it yourself, can you outline your proof and list (some of) the fishy points?

Comment: I've simply tried to use the definition of a general $L^p(X,\Sigma,\mu)$mainly paying attention to how the intagral of a function with respect $\#$ measure looks like . But I haven't achieved anything.

Comment: The integral with respect to the counting measure is nothing but the sum. I'm surprised if measure theory books don't mention this. (But I've been surprised before.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an outline for proving your statement.

1. $\ell^p$ is a space of (some) functions $\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$, and so is $L^p$ (with the choices indicated by OP). (I chose to work with the reals, but this choice is irrelevant.) The counting measure gives nonzero measure to all nonempty sets, so each equivalence class in $L^p$ only consists of one function. (As Nate Eldredge correctly reminded me, the $L^p$ space is a space of equivalence classes of functions rather than a space of functions. But now every function is equivalent to itself only, so we can regard $L^p$ as an actual space of functions.)
2. Every set is measurable with respect to the counting measure, so all functions $\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ are measurable.
3. It remains to show that a function has finite $\ell^p$ norm if and only if it has finite $L^p$ norm.
4. Let $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$. Then
   $$
   \|f\|_{\ell^p}^p
   =
   \sum_{n=1}^\infty|f(n)|^p
   =
   \int_{\mathbb N}|f(x)|^pd\#(x)
   =
   \|f\|_{L^p}^p.
   $$

If there are things that you are not convinced about, what are they?
I numbered the steps to make them easier to refer to.

Comment: There is one subtlety in step 1: in general, $L^p$ is not a space of functions, but a space of equivalence classes of functions under almost everywhere equality.  So it needs to be shown that in this case, different functions are inequivalent, i.e. that two functions are equal almost everywhere iff they are the same function.  (Of course, that easily follows from the fact that the only set with counting measure zero is the empty set.)  Then all the equivalence classes that make up $L^p$ are singletons and can be identified with functions.

Comment: @NateEldredge, good point. I'll add a note for that.

Comment: Of course, this generalised to arbitrary index set $\Gamma$ (countable or not), in which case one obtains the space $\ell_p(\Gamma)$.

Comment: Sorry the delay in answering. Thank you for the answer and the comments, especially Nate Eldredge's one, one of the things that didn't convinced me was exactly the fact that $L^p$ is not simply a set of functions. The main problem is that I don't get why $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(n)|^p=\int_{\Bbb N} |f(x)|^p d\#.$ I guess I should think about a little bit more.

Comment: @Claretta, you're welcome. To see why the integral is a sum, try to look at the definition of integrals step by step. It is much easier to see that for simple functions (although exact definitions of simpleness vary) and then extend to other cases. If you get stuck, do ask.